# How to save Images Quickly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ipod

I'm doing video conversion using **ffmpeg**. I'm getting the sequence of images. Now I am using

```
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(video.currentImage) writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
```

...to save the file into a directory. But this taking lots of time to save. I need to save this image quickly.

Comment: This post may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224369/uiimagepngrepresentation-slow-or-am-i-doing-something-wrong (if you're willing to save as JPEG over PNG - I am not well versed on the pros/cons of each format)

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply.. I already tried that but I did some mistakes on that.. But now it's working better than the .png format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try With UIImageJPEGRepresentation (  UIImage *image,  CGFloat compressionQuality)